# JAVA How to get SWT or JFace internal images

Tags: java, swt, jface

Does anybody know where are and how can I obtain internal images which are used by SWT/JFace, like WARNING, ERROR or INFORMATION icons and others...? Where are they situated and how to get them into my code ?

Answer (score 3):

Some parts of JFace uses images from `JFaceResources` rather than `SWT`. You find these as

```
Image i = JFaceResources.getImage(...);
```

Unfortunately, everybody can install new images into the resource manager, so there are no way to predict the names of images. Some general images are installed in `JFaceResources.initializeDefaultImages()`.

(If you have images, font or colors you use multiple times across your application, then look into `JFaceResources`.)

Also - if you are using Eclipse RCP - you can find a number of images using

```
Image i = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages...);
```

You can find additional constants in `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.SharedImages` and `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEInternalWorkbenchImages` (for IDEs).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getSystemImage()` method of `Display` to get those images.
For example:

```
Display d = Display.getCurrent(); 
Image img = d.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING);
```

Hope that helps